# How to get photo from Cordova Camera Preview Plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin 
[Cordova Camera Preview Plugin](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview)

When i take photo, i got an error. I dont know how to read image from this URL. i want base64 of that image.

Here is error image:

[image]

here is my HTML

```
<div class="controls">
  <div class="block">
    <button id="startCameraButton">Start Camera at back</button>
    <button id="stopCameraButton">Stop Camera</button>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <p><button id="startCameraAnotherPosButton">Start Camera at front</button></p>

    <p>Color Effect:
    <select id="colorEffectCombo">
      <option selected value="none">None</option>
      <option value="aqua">Aqua</option>
      <option value="blackboard">Blackboard</option>
      <option value="mono">Mono</option>
      <option value="negative">Negative</option>
      <option value="posterize">Posterize</option>
      <option value="sepia">Sepia</option>
      <option value="solarize">Solarize</option>
      <option value="whiteboard">Whiteboard</option>
    </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button id="takePictureButton">Take Picture</button>
    <button id="switchCameraButton">Switch Camera</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button id="hideButton">Hide</button>
    <button id="showButton">Show</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pictures">
  <p><img id="previewPicture" width="200"/></p>
  <p><img id="originalPicture" width="200"/></p>
</div>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var app = {
  startCamera: function(){
    console.log('starting camera');
    // var tapEnabled = true; //enable tap take picture
    var dragEnabled = true; //enable preview box drag across the screen
    // var toBack = true; //send preview box to the back of the webview
    var rect = {x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height:300};
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, "front", dragEnabled)
  },
  stopCamera: function(){
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.stopCamera();
  },

  startCameraAnotherPos: function(){
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera({x: 50, y: 100, width: 300, height:300, camera: "back", tapPhoto: true, previewDrag: true, toBack: false});
  },

  takePicture: function(){
    console.log('taking picture..');
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.takePicture({maxWidth: 640, maxHeight: 640});
  },

  takepicturehandler: function(){
    console.log('taking..');
  },

  switchCamera: function(){
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.switchCamera();
  },

  show: function(){
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.show();
  },

  hide: function(){
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.hide();
  },

  colorEffectChanged: function(){
    var effect = document.getElementById('colorEffectCombo').value;
    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.setColorEffect(effect);
  },


  init: function(){
    document.getElementById('startCameraButton').addEventListener('click', this.startCamera, false);
    document.getElementById('startCameraAnotherPosButton').addEventListener('click', this.startCameraAnotherPos, false);

    document.getElementById('stopCameraButton').addEventListener('click', this.stopCamera, false);
    document.getElementById('takePictureButton').addEventListener('click', this.takePicture, false);
    document.getElementById('switchCameraButton').addEventListener('click', this.switchCamera, false);
    document.getElementById('showButton').addEventListener('click', this.show, false);
    document.getElementById('hideButton').addEventListener('click', this.hide, false);
    document.getElementById('colorEffectCombo').addEventListener('change', this.colorEffectChanged, false);

    cordova.plugins.camerapreview.setOnPictureTakenHandler(function(result){
      console.log(result);
      document.getElementById('originalPicture').src = result[0];//originalPicturePath;
      document.getElementById('previewPicture').src = result[1];//previewPicturePath;
  });

  }
};

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){  
  app.init();
}, false);
```

Comment: I actually need the same thing, but cant get plugin to run. How did you get it to run, what is the version of Android you're testing on. On 6.0 this plugin has a permission bug, its kind of useless for me. See this https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/128

Comment: All right, I actually fixed the plugin itself and the java files, so now it works with android 6.0. Will try to use it tomorrow and I'll post the answer if i get something going

Comment: I am using this plugin on Android 7.0. well finally i am now able to get picture. i am directly reading the file from the returning url and converting it to base64. but the picture quality is so bad. Please if you find out and solution. let me know @Marko
[Check this](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/86)

Comment: So, you did not have to edit the .java files and install the cordova plugin compat in order to actually start this plugin on your phone? Cause I had to,  cause of the permissions in runtime. Anyway, can you now edit your question with the code you made work?

Comment: Did you get toBack:true to work for you?

Comment: Well i am not using that plugin now, i used another one. But what i did is instead of showing that image in preview , i just read that path using FileReader and convert it directly into base64. By doing so, i was able to get base64 of that image. then i send that base64 to server and save that on s3. i will share that code with you [click here](goo.gl/YfYzRM)

Comment: [This is the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__NWg94G1XAdXJiSUZvb2J4SUk/view)

Comment: So which plugin are you using then? What was the thing you were trying to do when you opted out for camera-preview plugin? What I'm trying to do is create my own camera looks with custom buttons and area im taking picture of, thats why i needed this plugin, but the toBack:true parameter isnt working

Comment: I mean if you just wanted to get a photo and upload it somewhere, i.e. you dont need a custom camera view, you could just go with the cordova-plugin-camera, that works 100% and its gonna save you a lot of trouble

Comment: Actually what i want is i wanna show an overlay on camera like an image on camera and then person will able to click the picture in the same position as shown in the overlay. Thats why i wanna use this plugin. but this will taking to much time so i switched to different plugin which is cordova-plugin-media-capture. It is not related to that plugin which i want. it Just take picture and upload it on s3. if in future you will successful and gets what you want then please share your code with me because in future i have to work on it.

Comment: ok, got it. I pretty much wasted an entire day trying to use that plugin and its a headache, i'll try with different approaches and hopefully ill get something working

Answer (score 1):

In order for the picture to be usable, it needs to be 'stored' temporarily, both in the right format and with the proper path. Here is an example of a promise-based function:

public base64Image: any;
public message: any;

```
takePicture() {
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture({
      quality: 50
    }).then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
      this.message = 'Problem accessing the camera ' + err;
    });
  }
```

Here, base64Image is the path to your image, which you may use in an img tag:

```
<img src="{{base64Image}}">
```